# How to put IF condition while reading SQL Server query data in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

Dears,
I'm designing a report in C# using windows form linked to SQL Server table. The result of the query is usually GP% numbers like : 30% or 40% and so on. These numbers are string by the way. I want to put the SQL Server result "30% for example in the array in c#. if no problem with the number it will be added simply like this :

```
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd43 = new SqlCommand(Product1ProfitPercentQuery, conn);
        SqlDataReader rd43 = cmd43.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd43.Read())
        {

            string Product1= rd43.GetString(0);
            Products.Add(Product1);
        }
        rd43.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

/*But the problem is that some times the query's result is Null. The array will not accept to put Null result. I want to put a condition in the array reader as the following but its't working :*/

```
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd43 = new SqlCommand(Product1ProfitPercentQuery, conn);
        SqlDataReader rd43 = cmd43.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd43.Read())
        {

            string Product1= rd43.GetString(0);
            if (Product1=="Null")
            {
                Products.Add("0");
            }
            else if (Product1!= "Null")
            {
                Products.Add(Product1);
            }

        }
        rd43.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

How can i write this condition please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HasRows` property of the SqlDataReader to see if the recordest was populated or null, and you could wrap your `while` loop within it.

```
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd43 = new SqlCommand(Product1ProfitPercentQuery, conn);
    SqlDataReader rd43 = cmd43.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd43.HasRows) {
        while (rd43.Read())
        {
            string Product1= rd43.GetString(0);
            Products.Add(Product1);
        }
    }
    rd43.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Ok will try it. Thanks a million ☺

Answer (score 0):

You need to check SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(0) in your if statement like below:

```
        if (rd43.IsDBNull(0))
        {
            Products.Add("0");
        }
        else
        {
            Products.Add(rd43.GetString(0));
        }
```

More information about it you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Clear and easy. Appreciate your inputs ☺

Answer (score 0):

If the column is `null`, the reader will return a SQL `DBNull` value, not a `string` representation of `null`. Try something like this:

```
string Product1= rd43.GetString(0);
if(rd43.IsDBNull(Product1))
{
    Products.Add("0");
}
else
{
    Products.Add(Product1);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your kind support